# Boundary is a union of orbits with strictly lower dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm stuck on the proof of the following propsition in Humphreys Linear Algebraic Groups:

> Let $G$ be an algebraic group acting morphically on a variety $X$.  Then each orbit is a smooth, locally closed subset of $X$, whose boundary is a union of orbits of strictly lower dimension.

Proof: Let $Y$ be an orbit in $X$.  As the continuous image of a closed set, $Y$ is constructible, and hence contains an open dense subset of $\overline{Y}$.  But $G$ acts transitively on $Y$ (and hence stablizes $\overline{Y}$), so $Y$ is smooth and contains a neighborhood in $\overline{Y}$ of each of its points, i.e. $Y$ is open in $\overline{Y}$.  Therefore, $\overline Y \setminus Y$ is closed and of strictly lower dimension than $\overline{Y}$.  Being $G$-stable, this boundary is just a union of other orbits.

Two questions: first, why is $Y$ is open in $\overline{Y}$?  I don't understand why each point in $Y$ admits an open neighborhood in $\overline{Y}$.  Second, why is $\overline{Y} \setminus Y$ of strictly lower dimension than $\overline{Y}$?

Comment: Why does transitivity of the action mean that the closure is stabilized?

Comment: A function is continuous if and only if it maps the image of the closure of a set is contained in the closure of the image.  For a fixed $g \in G$, the function $$h: X \rightarrow X, x \mapsto g.x$$ is continuous.  Then $h(\overline{Y}) \subseteq \overline{h(Y)} = \overline{Y}$.

Comment: Why is $Y$ smooth?

Comment: The image of any morphism of varieties contains a nonempty open subset of its closure. 
 $Y$ is the image of the morphism of varieties $G \rightarrow X, g \mapsto g.x$.  Hence it contains a nonempty open subset $U$ of $\overline{Y}$.  The smooth points in $\overline{Y}$ are dense in $\overline{Y}$, so $U$ contains at least one smooth point.  Hence every point in $Y$ is smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ with $Y=G\cdot x$. There is a subset $U\subseteq Y$, which is open and dense in $\bar{Y}$, so you can write the orbit as union of open sets

$$G\cdot x=\bigcup_{g\in G} g\cdot U, $$
where $g\cdot U$ is open as isomorphic image of an open set.

$\overline{G\cdot x}\setminus G\cdot x$ is a closed subset and every irreducible component of it is a proper subset of a irreducible component of $\overline{G\cdot x}$, because $G\cdot x$ is dense in $\overline{G\cdot x}$. So by definition of krull dimension it has stricly lower dimension.

Comment: Why is it the case that if $A$ Is a closed subset of an irreducible variety $B$, and $B \setminus A$ is dense in $B$, then $\textrm{Dim } A < \textrm{Dim } B$?

Comment: The dimension is the maximal length of chains of distinct nonempty subvarieties, isn't it?

Comment: Well, distinct nonempty closed irreducible sets.  I am just not seeing why every irreducible component of $\overline{Y} \setminus Y$ is a proper subset of an irreducible component of $\overline{Y}$.

Comment: If the one irreducible component of $\bar{Y}\setminus Y$ is the same as a irreducible component of $\bar{Y}$ then $Y$ couldn't be dense.

Comment: "If $X_1, ... , X_n$ are the irreducible components of a Noetherian space $X$, then an open set $U$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $U \cap X_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $i$."  That was the result I needed, thank you.